# Is there a way to stop Chrome/Firefox record history of a 'particular' website?

Tags: firefox, chromium, privacy

I want Chrome/Firefox NOT to record history of a  'particular' website. Is it possible to do so? I searched in preferences, but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Usually if you want no records of visiting a web page, you don't want anything to be recorded from this web page, so it would be strange to *store* a list of particular websites without history records. But yes, it might be usefull if you just want not to store sessions and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of chrome there is an Extension called "Ghost Incognito",
Ghost incognito make sure that some domains always open in incognito mode. When navigating to a listed domain, the tab will open in a new incognito window.

Answer (score 16):

**This isn't the exact solution you want, but I couldn't find another way to do it more in line with the original question.**

### Chrome

The solution is to use incognito mode. To get to incognito mode, use the following keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

### Firefox

The solution is to use private browsing. To start private browsing, use the following keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You could also use these

[history site blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-site-blocker/bkgnheiibhnjklgimaldgngjcfblachh) (for Chrome)

> Note that while sites are prevented from being inserted into the history, autocomplete still works on URLs from those sites. I actually like the convenience of this, but it's definitely less secure than Incognito, which prevents those URLs from showing up in autocomplete.

[History blocker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/historyblock/) (for Firefox)